# Angular 2 transclusion, directive content into "alt"

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a simple question here, and yet can't find a solution...
So here is my logo.components.ts :

```
import {Component} from '../../../../frameworks/core/index';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-logo',
  templateUrl: 'logo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['logo.component.css']
})
export class LogoComponent  {}
```

So i'm importing it in my home.component.ts :

```
import {LogoComponent} from '../../frameworks/mysite/components/logo/logo.component';

<my-logo>AltText</my-logo>
```

So my template logo.component.html looks like this:

```
<div class="logo-icon">
  <img alt="" src="../../images/logo-icon.svg" />
</div>
```

So i would like my

```
<my-logo>AltText... or any content text from here.... </my-logo>
```

directive content inserted into my logo.component.html , 
`<img alt="INSERTED HERE" src="../../images/logo-icon.svg" />`.

I know about the

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

But in this case i don't know the proper way to insert in into "alt"...
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't transclude into an attribute, only to elements children.

You can pass the value as attribute

```
<my-logo alt="AltText"></my-logo>
```

In your component

```
@Component({
  template: `
<div class="logo-icon">
  <img [alt]="alt" src="../../images/logo-icon.svg" />
</div>
`
})
export class MyLogo {
  @Input() alt:string;
}
```

If you still want to use transclude, you can transclude it using `<ng-content>`, the read the transcluded content from the DOM and assign it to a property you bind `<img [alt]="...">` to but that's quite cumbersome.

**Update - using transclusion**

```
<div class="logo-icon">
  <div #wrapper hidden="true"><ng-content></ng-content><div>
  <img [alt]="alt" src="../../images/logo-icon.svg" />
</div>
```

get the transcluded content

```
export class LogoComponent  {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') content:ElementRef; 

  ngAfterViewInitInit():any {
    this.alt = this.content.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i would still like to know if there is to get text from the inside the directive `<my-logo>AltText</my-logo>` and stick it into alt, with no adding  `alt="..."` into `<my-logo>`
I've recently started working with angular framework, so maybe asking pretty dumb question, coz of lack of experience ....

Comment: I updated my answer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/37586026/217408

Comment: `@Input() alt:string;`
 - worked fine actually
`@ViewChild('wrapper') content:ElementRef;` - this approach did not work though, i double checked everything and yet it says alt = 'undefined'.

Comment: You can't access `@ViewChild()` results in the constructor, only in or after `ngAfterViewInit()`. If input works for you it's fine of course as well.