# Access transcluded content

Tags: angular

I have a componenet which i use to display a block of code which is transcluded in the component

```
<gs-code> console.log("Asd")</gs-code>
```

The component looks like this

**code.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'gs-code',
        providers: [],
        viewProviders: [],
        templateUrl: './code.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./code.component.less']
    })
    export class GsCodeComponent {
        @Input() lang: string;
        @Input() currentLang: string;
        @ContentChild('content') content;
        copied(event) {
            console.log(event);
        }

        ngAfterContentInit() {
            console.log(this.content, "content");
        }
    }
```

**code.component.html**

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
   <ng-content #content></ng-content>
</pre>
<button class="btn btn-sm" title="Copy to clipboard" (click)="copied(content.innerHtml)"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i></button>
```

How can I get the transcluded text in the component?
I have tried using `contentChild` and `#content` as the `<ng-content #content></ng-content>`. But these have not worked.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573439/get-component-child-as-string/37586026#37586026

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<ng-content>` element will never be added to the DOM itself, therefore adding a template variable and querying for it doesn't work.
You can wrap `<ng-content>` with another element and add the template variable there and query this element using `@ViewChild()`.

Then you can just get the `innerHTML` of the wrapper element

```
@Component({
    selector: 'item',
    template: '<div #wrapper><ng-content></ng-content></div>'})
class Item implements AfterContentInit {

    @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;
    @Input() type:string = "type-goes-here";

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log(this.wrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML); // or `wrapper.text`
    }
}
```

See also [Get component child as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573439/get-component-child-as-string/37586026#37586026)

Comment: Do you have a SO web ring plugin making these links at the bottom? I'm about four layers deep in "See also" references now. ;^D

Comment: @ruffin LOL was not intentional. I just like to add links to related stuff to keep things connected.