# *ngIf <ng-content> Transclusion gets from outside any content possible?

Tags: angular, typescript

I got in my Angular4 Project this small code:

```
<div class="divider"></div>

<ng-content select=".nav-toggle"></ng-content>
```

Now i want to make the divider only visible, if any content comes from outside in the ng-content tag. Is this possible? I absolutely cant find any informations about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no good way to query for arbitrary projected content

```
@Component({
    selector: 'item',
    template: `
<div *ngIf="divider" class="divider"></div>
<div #wrapper><ng-content select=".nav-toggle"></ng-content></div>'})
class Item implements AfterContentInit {

    @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;

    divider:boolean = false;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
      console.log(this.wrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML); // or `wrapper.text`
      this.divider = !!this.wrapper.nativeElement.children;
    }
}
```

See also [Access transcluded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737037/access-transcluded-content/40737143#40737143)

If you know the projected content is a specific Angular component or the element has a specific template variable applied, you can use `@ContentChildren()` (see also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)).

Comment: you forgot the `.nativeElement` in `console.log(this.wrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML)`

Comment: @n00dl3 you're right. Thanks a lot for the hint - fixed.

Comment: you missed one ;)

Comment: @n00dl3 time for weekend ;-) Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer! But i think, this is to much overdosed for a divider. For sure in some cases where you have no choise is this a good solution. Thanks again for this!

Comment: @Budi there is an open issue that you might find interesting : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563 as this issue has been openned by Miško Hevery I guess it will get implemented some day...