# In angular2, how can I detect is there any ng-content?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngcontent

plnkr demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mEYYjkYculd6epbIHo5y?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-demo',
  template: `This is <ng-content select=".content"></ng-content>`
})
export class DemoComponent { name = 'Angular'; }

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <my-demo><div class="content">In Content</div></my-demo>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

I want to conditional `ng-content`, like

```
<ng-template *ngIf='hasContent(".content"); else noContent'>
This is <ng-content select=".content"></ng-content>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #noContent>No content</ng-template>
```

Is there possible in angular2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template: `This is <span #wrapper>
  <ng-content select=".content"></ng-content>
  </span>`
```

```
@ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.wrapper.innerHTML); // or `wrapper.text`
}
```

See also

- [Get component child as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573439/get-component-child-as-string/37586026#37586026)
- [Access transcluded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737037/access-transcluded-content/40737143#40737143)

Answer (score 1):

Günter Zöchbauer's solution is acceptable, doesn't affect the useage, let the component detect this, I also found a easier way to do this without any json by using the `:empty`

```
<!-- must no content: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/ -->
<!--@formatter:off-->
<div class="title"><ng-content select=".nav-title"></ng-content></div>
<!--@formatter:on-->

.title:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Works for any html+css.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use conditional statement with `*ngIf` and `else` the yes it's possible

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-demo',
  template: `<div *ngIf='content; else noContent'>
This is <ng-content select=".content"></ng-content>
</div>

<ng-template #noContent>No content</ng-template>`
})
export class DemoComponent { name = 'Angular'; content = true}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/N0dMUIkcgdE29SnCKkMD?p=preview)

Comment: Can you explain how this helps?