# angular2 feeding data back to `<template>` from `[ngTemplateOutlet]`

Tags: angular

So I have a component with a `<template>`

```
<some-component [data]="someArray">
  <template>foo<template>
</some-component>
```

and it's using this to get hold of the template

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef)
public tmpl: TemplateRef<any>;
```

which is then used in its template like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of someArrayFromDataInput">
  <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tmpl"></template>
</div>
```

now I would like to be able to print some data from `item` in the original template, basically to be able to do this

```
<some-component [data]="someArray">
  <template>foo {{ item }}<template>
</some-component>
```

is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Updated to match Angular 5+ api
`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/37654077/301596

---

Once this lands https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9042 it will work like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of someArrayFromDataInput">
  <template 
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
      item: item
    }" 
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="tmpl"></template>
</div>
```

+

```
<some-component [data]="someArray">
  <template let-item="item">foo {{ item }}<template>
</some-component>
```

// edit: landed

Comment: Is there a way to "automatically" put a `let-item="item"` on some-component? or better yet do what ngFor does, and expand `someDir="foo"` into `let-foo="item"` for proper aliasing?

Answer (score 0):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

Looks like you are asking for the same feature requested in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8368 (NgTemplateOutlet)

**Update**

See [How to repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593/how-to-repeat-a-piece-of-html-multiple-times-without-ngfor-and-without-anoher-c/37676946#37676946) for working Plunker examples.

Comment: And template has been replaced by ng-template.