# Can't bind to 'ngTemplateOutletContext'

Tags: angular

I have converted Angular 4 to Angular 6 and I have built the project and geting the following error. Any idea how to handle?

> Can't bind to 'ngTemplateOutletContext' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'ng-container'.

```
<ul *ngIf="item.childrens != undefined && item.childrens.length > 0">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutletContext="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.childrens }"></ng-container>
</ul>
```

My question is on `TemplateOutletContext`, not `TemplateOutlet`.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. But it's already answered actually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221088/cant-bind-to-ngoutletcontext-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ng-template

Comment: It has not been answered, there is no accepted answer. If you check given answer, I already changed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#inputs):

> `ngTemplateOutletContext` bound to
>   `NgTemplateOutlet.ngTemplateOutletContext`

So you would be able to attach context in the following way:

```
<ng-container 
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="recursiveList"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item.childrens }"></ng-container>
```

Or:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context: { $implicit: item.childrens }"></ng-container>
```

Angular needs to know what view you intend on adding your context object to, so `ngTemplateOutletContext` won't work on its own AFAIK.

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.0.7/packages/common/src/directives/ng_template_outlet.ts#L10-L100), [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kf3ccy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

The above-accpected answer did not work for me. People you are looking for this in the future.

Here is the correct syntax, when you want to send the dynamic data to ng-template as input/variable using ngTemplateOutletContext like (item.childrens rather than the item itself).

```
<div>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateName"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: 'Hello World', object2: 'John Doe'}">
 </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #templateName let-default let-object2="object2">
    {{default}}
    {{object2}}
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For others, you might also be missing import for **CommonModule** or **NgTemplateOutlet**, which was issue in my case