# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngOutletContext' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'. 1. If 'ngOutletContext' is an Angula

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7, angular4-forms

Hi My team and I have updated our angular app from 4.3.2 to angular 7.1.3. All packages migrated and angular.json pointing to the same. But in console we receive "Can't bind to 'ngOutletContext'". No where in the app this attribute is used. It only appears in Vendor.js. Error message is below.

compiler.js:2427 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngOutletContext' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'.
1. If 'ngOutletContext' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("    
            ][ngOutletContext]="day.context">
          
        
"): ng:///NgbDatepickerModule/NgbDatepickerMonthView.html@13:58
Property binding ngOutletContext not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("        [class.hidden]="isHidden(day)">
          
            [ERROR ->]
        "): ng:///NgbDatepickerModule/NgbDatepickerMonthView.html@13:12
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2427)
    at TemplateParser.push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20311)
    at JitCompiler.push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25857)
    at JitCompiler.push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25844)
    at compiler.js:25787
    at Set.forEach ()
    at JitCompiler.push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25787)
    at compiler.js:25697
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2418)
    at JitCompiler.push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25696)
1. If 'ngOutletContext' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component

Current Angular setup is.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.3",
    "@biesbjerg/ng2-translate-extract": "^0.6.0",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/geojson": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "@types/leaflet": "^0.7.31",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.61",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
    "codelyzer": "2.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "env2json": "^1.0.0",
    "hads": "1.3.3",
    "htmlhint": "0.9.13",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "stylelint": "7.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "16.0.0",
    "ts-node": "3.0.2",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221088/cant-bind-to-ngoutletcontext-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ng-template

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya As indicated in the description no where in the code the [ngOutletContext] is present. We have looked everywhere. The above question answers to change the <ng-template> tag. Here in our app we do not have the tag anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ngOutletContext with ngTemplateOutletContext.

its mentioned in angular update guide. for complete details visit

```
https://update.angular.io/
```

Comment: We have used both angular.io/cli/update and update.angular.io for our migration. In VS Code search no where we can find "ngOutletContext "

Comment: read the error ng:///NgbDatepickerModule/NgbDatepickerMonthView.html@13:58 Property binding ngOutletContext not used by any directive on an embedded template.........., are you using a third-party library, for DatePicker I guess the issue might be over there