# Passing ngFor variable to an ngIf template

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if, ng-template

How do I pass the current variable in an ngFor loop to ngIf, if it is using templates with then/else syntax?

It appears that they pass through fine when used inline, but aren't accessible from a template, for example:

```
<ul *ngFor="let number of numbers">
  <ng-container *ngIf="number % 2 == 0; then even_tpl; else odd_tpl"><>/ng-container>
</ul>


<ng-template #odd_tpl>
  <li>Odd: {{number}}</li>  
</ng-template>

<ng-template #even_tpl>
  <li>Even: {{number}}</li>  
</ng-template>
```

The templates don't seem to have access to `number` at all, but it works if used inline.

A full example of the working and not-working versions in the following link: [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/yyM6ew/)

Comment: @Guntram : can you please add any demo link ? because i am getting blank response. Thanks

Comment: i moved it into an answer...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

All you need is to use `[ngTemplateOutletContext]` **[Read More](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)**

Here is the way how you can achieve that :

```
<div>
  <h3>All Templates</h3>
  <ul *ngFor="let number of numbers">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]='number % 2 == 0 ? even_tpl : odd_tpl' [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{number:number}"></ng-container>
  </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #odd_tpl let-number='number'>
  <li>Odd: {{number}}</li>  
</ng-template>

<ng-template #even_tpl let-number='number'>
  <li>Even: {{number}}</li>  
</ng-template>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-container-conditional)**

Comment: Thanks - I'd seen the docs on `ngTemplateOutlet` but hadn't managed to grok it into this situation - seeing a working example makes it clear how to use it!

Comment: @match, Glad you figure it out , Its happens sometimes :) , happy coding.

Answer (score 7):

look here: [Pass variable in Angular 2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726749/pass-variable-in-angular-2-template)

```
<div *ngFor="foo in foos">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inner; context:{name:foo}"></ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #inner let-name="name">
    {{ name }}
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Here's a plunker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418598/cant-get-ngtemplateoutlet-to-work

Answer (score 1):

It's because the way template scope works. Templates in Angular have dynamic scope instead of regular javascript lexical scope, that means, the `{{ number }}` expression inside the `ng-template` is not pointing to the same `number` variable in your `*ngFor`, although one should think it would since you're kinda *evaluating* the template expression where `<ng-container>` is.

If you actually define a `number` property in your `AppComponent`, let's say `number = 42`, you can see that all the `{{number}}` expressions inside `<ng-template>` evaluates to `42`.

So either you should define your templates inside the scope of the `*ngFor`, where the `number` variable has the desired value, or somehow pass this value to both `even_tpl` and `odd_tpl`. As @Vivek has pointed out, you can do this with `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ngTemplateOutletContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple more (similar) options for multiple arguments, this one includes using 'ngTemplateOutletContext' and also a condition (in 4th argument - for fun).

... should work by copy and paste ...

```
            <!-- DEMO using: 
                "=templateID; context:{prop:value, ...}"
                ( 4 arguments demo)
                Note: $implicit identifies the default argument in the template.
                        The template does not need to assign the argument name,
                        - see the 3rd argument
            -->
    <div *ngFor="let item of ['Aaa', 'Bbb', 'Ccc']; index as ix">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate1; 
                    context:{cDemoName:'Option 1:',
                             cIx:ix+1, 
                             $implicit:item, 
                             cIsEven: ((ix % 2) === 0) ? 'true' : 'false' }">
        </ng-container>
    </div>

    <hr>

            <!-- DEMO using: 
                [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateID"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{"=templateID; context:{prop:value, ...}"
            -->

    <div *ngFor="let item of ['Dddd', 'Eee', 'Fff']; index as ix">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate1"
                      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
                        cDemoName:'Option 2',
                        cIx:ix+1, 
                        $implicit:item, 
                        cIsEven: ((ix % 2) === 0) ? 'true' : 'false' }
                    ">
        </ng-container>
    </div>

            <!-- DEMO template: 
                ( 4 arguments expected)
            -->
    <ng-template #myTemplate1 
            let-cDemoName="cDemoName"
            let-cIx="cIx"
            let-cItem
            let-cIsEven="cIsEven">

        Context arguments demo name: {{cDemoName}} <br>
        . . . . . Context index: {{cIx}} <br>
        . . . . . Context item: --- {{ cItem }} --- <br>
        . . . . . Context is-even: {{ cIsEven }} <br>
        <br>
    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers use the same name for key-value, So at the first look, it makes me confuse.

Here working example for Angular 10

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataList">
       <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="data.istruevalue ? truevalue : falsevalue ; context: { passdata:data}"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #truevalue let-info="passdata">    
        <label >true : {{info.name}}</label><br>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #falsevalue let-info="passdata">   
        <label >false : {{info.name}}</label><br>
</ng-template>
```