# Using ng-template and ngIf together where ngIf can access the paased argument

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ng-template

```
<div>
  <h3>All Templates</h3>
  <ul *ngFor="let number of numbers">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]='number % 2 == 0 ? even_tpl : odd_tpl' [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{number:number}"></ng-container>
  </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #odd_tpl let-number='number'>
  <li>Odd: {{number}}</li>  
</ng-template>

<ng-template #even_tpl let-number='number'>
  <li>Even: {{number}}</li>  
</ng-template>
```

<sub>PS. sample code from Vivek Doshi's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48205686/1603234)</sub>.

but what I'm looking for is to only go-inside ng-template when a condition meets, something like this:

```
<ng-template #odd_tpl let-number='number' *ngIf="number > 10">
  <li>Odd: {{number}}</li>  
</ng-template>
```

but it is showing an error:

> Identifier 'number' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member `ng`.

I want to access the passed argument `number`, is this possible?

Comment: Try using `<ng-container *ngIf"` inside `ng-template`

Comment: Yeah, it worked that way but even if condition won't meet it will add a container in DOM. So that's why I don't want to use that.

Comment: Oh, my bad, it is adding some element in DOM because of previous ngFor loop from where I'm calling this template. So the only solution is to use `ng-container` with `ngIf`.

Answer (score 2):

So as per yurzui commented I've used ng-container, previously there was some element getting added to the DOM but it was a mistake which I fixed and now things are works just fine.

I can check for the condition like this -

```
<ng-template #odd_tpl let-number='number'>
   <ng-container *ngIf="number > 10">
     <li>Odd: {{number}}</li>  
   </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```