# Reusable list of custom components in Angular

Tags: angular, list, angular2-template, children, ngfor

I want to create reusable SortedList Component in Angular5. The list should accept any array of listItems (objects) as attribute. From ListContainer component I want to use the list and pass a list item template as follows:

```
<div class='list-container'>
<SortedList [items]='getListItems()' [categories]='getSortCategories()' >
  <ACustomItem [item]='item'></AcustomItem>
</SortedList
<div>
```

`ACustomItem` will be any component that accepts [item], the html will vary depends on implementation.

Inside my SortList I have:

```
<div class='sorted-list'>
  <div class='sorted-list__header'>
    <div class='sorted-list__header-title'>{{title}}</div>
    <select [(ngModel)]='selectedCategory' (ngModelChange)='onCategoryChange($event)'>
      <option *ngFor='let category of categories' [ngValue]='category.id'>{{category.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='sorted-list__body'>
    <div *ngFor="let item of data | orderBy: selectedCategory.id ">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above does not work, what is missing here? I assume I need to use `ng-template` here but not sure how it should be embedded here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654004/angular2-feeding-data-back-to-template-from-ngtemplateoutlet/37662335#37662335) solution and modified it for Angular 5 and your specific components. As `ngOutletContext` was [removed](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2658) from version 5 of Angular [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skdkvq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsorted-list%2Fsorted-list.component.html) is an example in stackblitz.

**SortedList component template**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <template [ngTemplateOutletContext]='{item: item}' [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateVariable"></template>
</div>
```

**SortedList component ts**

```
@Input() items: any[];
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateVariable: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**App component template**

```
<app-sorted-list [items]="myItems">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <!--Here can be any component-->
        <app-sorted-list-item [item]="item"></app-sorted-list-item>
    </ng-template> 
</app-sorted-list>
```