# Component transclude with inline template

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'm using Angular 2-rc3 and have a `Component` and I want to apply transclusion, just in a bit of a different way. Here's my component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-list',
    template: `<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of data">
            -- insert template here --
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </li>
    </ul>`
})
export class MyListComponent {
    @Input() data: any[];
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
<my-list [data]="cars">
    <div>{{item.make | uppercase}}</div>
</my-list>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to define an inline template that will be used by my component. Now this goes horribly wrong. First off, a databinding exception saying it `can't read property 'make' of undefined`. It's trying to read `item.make` off of my surrounding component, not of the `MyListComponent`. But even if I temporarily disable this for now:

```
<my-list [data]="cars">
    <div>{item.make | uppercase}</div>
</my-list>
```

Then the second problem appears:

```
-- insert template here --
-- insert template here --
-- insert template here --
-- insert template here --
{item.make | uppercase}
```

So Angular doesn't actually copy the template for use within the `*ngFor`, it just binds the elements and they end up associated with the last item.

**How do I get this to work?**

I had the same issue with AngularJS, where [petebacondarwin posted a solution to manipulate the DOM through compile](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874#issuecomment-46410994), which was great. I have this option with Angular 2 as well by injecting `ElementRef` in my component, but! One big difference is that `compile` in AngularJS went off before databinding, meaning there were no problems using `{{item.make}}` in the template. With Angular 2, this seems to be a no-go since `{{item}}` is being parsed before-hand. So what's the best way to go about this? Using the slightly different notation `[[item]]` and string replacing the entire thing doesn't seem the most elegant way...

Thanks in advance!

// Edit: Here's a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/M5FMnEB93uSUhXFKOc4Y?p=preview) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It would be great to have a Plunker that allows to reproduce where everything is in place how you want to use it. I find it hard to, for example, figure out what "insert template here" is supposed to mean exactly.

Comment: @J.P.tenBerge I had a similar issue and [found a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174837/how-to-create-a-component-with-a-dynamic-template-component-transclude-with-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To spell out the `ngForTemplate` method:

(**As of Angular 4** the element is now called `<ng-template>`.)

1. Use a `<template>` tag in both the outer and inner components, instead of `<ng-content>`.
2. The `<li>` is moved to the app.component html, and the `<template>` on this component has a special **'let-'** attribute which references the iterated variable in the inner component:

   ```
   <my-list [data]="cars">
     <template let-item>
       <li>
         <div>{{item.make | uppercase}}</div>
       </li>
     </template>
   </my-list>
   ```
3. The inner component has `<template>` as well and uses a variant of ngFor like so:

   ```
   <ul>
       <template #items ngFor [ngForOf]="data" [ngForTemplate]="tmpl">
           -- insert template here --
       </template>
   </ul>
   ```
4. The 'tmpl' variable assigned to the ngForTemplate attribute needs to be fetched in the component code:

   ```
   export class MyListComponent {
       @Input() data: any[];
       @ContentChild(TemplateRef) tmpl: TemplateRef;
   }
   ```
5. @ContentChild and TemplateRef are angular bits, so need to be imported

   ```
   import { Component, Input, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
   ```

See the fork of your plunkr with these changes in here [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7552K7qIWIzNCf7GsKSR?p=preview).

This isn't the most satisfactory solution for your stated problem, since you're passing the data in to the list you might as well have the ngFor on the outer. Plus, the additional content (the literal '-- insert template here --') gets dropped, so it you wanted to display that it must be on the outer template as well.

I can see it might be useful where the iteration is provided within the inner component (say from a service call), and maybe to do some manipulation of the template in code.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer and the plunkr. Though this seems to work, in my case when I have a dynamic list nothing is rendered in the list. Though if I inspect the DOM I can see there are template bindings. Any idea as to what's going on?

Comment: Not sure of the scenario - I can add cars to the list at runtine with a button and click event handler, and they show up in the list.

Comment: Spent many hours back in August to find a solution. This answer is soooo helpful. It just works. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

- `<ng-content>` inside `*ngFor` doesn't work, therefore

  ```
  <li *ngFor="let item of data">
      -- insert template here --
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  </li>
  ```

won't do anything meaningful. Everything will be transcluded to the first `<ng-content>`

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563 might solve some of your requirements.

- [Binding events when using a ngForTemplate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730210/binding-events-when-using-a-ngfortemplate-in-angular-2)
- [ng-content select bound variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225722/ng-content-select-bound-variable/37229495#37229495)
  might be an approach that would allow to do something similar like you demonstrated in your question.
  It requires the user of your component to wrap the content in a `<template>` tag.

Comment: The GitHub issue describes exactly what I need, but it's currently in the  state of "Needs Design" with no milestone so that doesn't offer me much. The first link seems exactly what I need, but works with an already outdated version of Angular (beta 8): referencing `TemplateRef` and the call to `setLocal()` don't work anymore. This solution does seem promising though and I saw a comment of yours about the `setLocal()` thing, I'm gonna play around some more with this.