# How to use an EmbeddedViewRef's context variable

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am a little unsure how to use the `EmbeddedViewRef`'s `context` variable. From what I gather from Angular 2's changelog, the `context` variable replaces the `setLocal` and `getLocal` methods as the mechanism for setting local variables in an embedded view.

After looking at [this blog post](http://teropa.info/blog/2016/03/06/writing-an-angular-2-template-directive.html), which uses `setLocal`, I have pieced together the following minimal example:

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core'

export class FooTemplateContext {
  constructor(public bar: string, public baz: string, public qux: string) {}
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[foo]'
})
export class Foo {
  constructor(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, templateRef: TemplateRef<FooTemplateContext>) {
    let context = new FooTemplateContext('bar', 'baz', 'qux');
    let view = viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef, context);
  }
}
```

---

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { Foo } from './foo.directive'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *foo>
        <ul>
          <li>{{bar}}</li>
          <li>{{baz}}</li>
          <li>{{qux}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Foo]
})
export class App {
  constructor() {}
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

A plunker for this example can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Cxr0cJnzEYvi38GeOZg?p=preview). When the list renders, each of the list items are empty. Am I thinking of the `context` in the wrong way or setting it improperly? If so, please let me know.

Comment: For the record, the `context` object you pass to `.createEmbeddedView` must be a class. Can't be a JSON Object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare variables and assign properties of the context to them:

cannonical form:

```
  <template foo let-bar="bar" let-baz="baz" let-qux="qux" >
    <ul>
      <li>{{bar}}</li>
      <li>{{baz}}</li>
      <li>{{qux}}</li>
    </ul>
  </template>
```

short form:

```
  <div *foo="let bar=bar let baz=baz let qux=qux">
    <ul>
      <li>{{bar}}</li>
      <li>{{baz}}</li>
      <li>{{qux}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/duXEHkOeBG1pr58LnozZ?p=preview)

See also [ng-content select bound variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225722/ng-content-select-bound-variable/37229495#37229495)