# Angular 4 Accessing Multiple Templates (ng-template) in Dynamic Form

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am following https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html guide to implement dynamic forms.

I now have a dynamic form component which takes formModel and form group as an input:

**mycomponent.html**

```
<dynamic-form [form]="form"
              [formModel]="formModel">
</dynamic-form>
```

My dynamic-form component loops through the formModel and render df-control component that renders specific control depending on the settings defined for that control in form model:

**dynamic-form.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">

    <div *ngFor="let controlModel of formModel" class="form-row">
        <df-control [controlModel]="controlModel" [form]="form" [formModel]="formModel">
        </df-control>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

For some of the form fields defined in my formModel I do not want it to be rendered through df-control. Instead, I want to be able to specify templates for such controls between dynamic-form tags. And want the appropriate template to be rendered when looping through formModel

For example if I have a form with 6 fields:

```
<dynamic-form [form]="form" [formModel]="formModel">
    <template [modelId]="'field3'">
        <p>my custom template for field 3</p>
    </template>
    <template [modelId]="'field5'">
        <p>my custom template for field 5</p>
    </template>
</dynamic-form>
```

I want all fields to be rendered in normal way exceped field3 and field5. For field3 and field5 I do not want to render df-control but instead I want appropriate template to be rendered

i.e. for field3:

```
<template [modelId]="'field3'">
     <p>my custom template for field 3</p>
</template>
```

and for field5:

```
<template [modelId]="'field5'">
     <p>my custom template for field 5</p>
</template>
```

Can anyone please guide how to achieve this?

I have found this which seems near to what I am looking for but its not very clear.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37229495/2755616

Any help would be really appreciated.